# Deleteing a panel after checkbox checked

Tags: c#, methods, checkbox

I have a code that generates multiple panels, each including some labels and comboboxes. One of the controls included in each panel is a checkbox, what I need to do is, that when user checks the checkbox, the whole panel where the checkbox was will be deleted.
Inside a foreach loop that generates the panels, the panel itself can be reached with name "Strip". Outside this loop, if I would transfer all necessary parameters(or arguments, not sure about the terminology here), it would be called after one of its labels "callsign", so when I need to get its name out into a method, I set as a parameter "callsign.Text".
Now, here is my Checbox generating code:

```
CheckBox check = new CheckBox();
check.Location = new Point(270, 10);
check.Name = "check:" + callsign.Text;
check.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(CheckCheckedChanged(callsign.Text));
Strip.Controls.Add(check);
```

and here is definition of method CheckCheckedChanged:

```
public void CheckCheckedChanged(string callsign, object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

... First of all, I get en error at line `check.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(CheckCheckedChanged(callsign.Text));`
It says, that "No overload for method `CheckCheckedChanged` takes 1 arguments". I dont know whats wrong, so thats my first question. The second is - I cant figure out how to write the method to delete the one specific panel named after the callsign.Text, if I would write just "callsign dispose" then I guess it wouldnt work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Delete `string callsign` from the event handler to eliminate the compiler error. You probably don't want to delete the panel but rather hide it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is remove the `string callsign` parameter from your event handler. That is what's causing the compiler error. So your method signature will look like this:

```
public void CheckCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Secondly, you need to change how the event is attached to event handler:

```
check.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(CheckCheckedChanged(callsign.Text));
```

will become:

```
check.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(CheckCheckedChanged);
```

Next, you want to put code into the event handler to get the state of the checkbox and set the visibility of the panel accordingly. You will replace the panel with the name of your panel.

```
public void CheckCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkbox = sender as CheckBox;
    if (checkbox != null)
    {
        ((Panel)checkbox.Parent).Visible = !checkbox.Checked;  // replace this with your panel
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, when I try to enter this method, the compiler just doesnt know the panel in it. I am quite confused now, as I am completely new to C# the only way that comes up on my mind is to _somehow_ get the whole panel as an argument into that method, which just sounds ridiculous, so I have no idea :(

Comment: What is the name of the panel you're trying to hide? You need to change `yourPanel` to the name of your panel. Do you have any more code you can post?

Comment: Name of the panel is a variable callsign. All I do, is download an xml file from web, and then using foreach I created needed amount of panels and fill them with informations, one of them is Label callsign, which gives name to the whole panel. As this method is outside the foreach loop, I cant acces the variables used there, neither the XmlNodeLists used.
Because each panel has different name and its own checkbox, each checkbox will have to call a different name of panel to hide.
I can upload the whole Visual Studio project somewhere, like on rapidshare, if thats okay for you.

Comment: I have just noticed your comment to the question - actually deleting the panel would be much better, because there will be many panels during runtime, and it might happen that later after deleting one panel there will occur a new one with the exactly same name, but the other values different.

Comment: http://rapidshare.com/files/3316938487/vESUP12-10-12.rar
here it is, thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, after updating to code written in the last edit, it works :) Thanks a lot!